# Date formatting error

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a field for Student Birth Date - defined as date, nothing else. When the form is in production whatever date you type in it the error says it's not formatted correctly.

I deleted it and re-added it, same error. I've typed the date in, chosen it from the date picker. Really if I choose today's date in another year the error goes away (e.g. today is 8/4/16, choosing 8/4/06 no error, 8/5/06 = error).

What's wrong with this?

[image: before date is added]

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some JavaScript libraries manipulate the default behavior of intrinsic types, such as Date, in ways that are not predictable or expected by Cognito Forms.  If you are seeing unexpected behavior for a form embedded in your website, try using the IFrame embed option, which eliminates JavaScript incompatibilities like this.

Comment: I'm using wordpress plugin, so I'm not sure how to make it an iframe? But it is an embedded form on a page so you are likely correct. It works in preview mode but not after I moved it to production.

Comment: Never mind, I got it! I had to find where I could insert source code on a page and then simply copy/pasted the code the publish button gave me. The date field is now working properly in production - thanks!!

Comment: I am glad I could help!